# An error occurred accessing the report SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We have an issue with a couple of users who are using our desktop application to generate reports using SSRS 2008.Desktop application is developed using C#.

This issue does not happen to all users but for a couple of them on a random basis.When these users try generating the report from the application at times  they get the below error message

> "An error occurred while accessing the report.Please check your network connection and try again.
>   Full error message: The operation has timed out Error number Timeout".

We are sure that the issue is not with the query getting timed-out as other users can generate the same report at the same time.

We did check the logs on the report server but couldn't find anything worthful.

I doubt it has something to do with the Authentication as the users can directly log on to Reporting Manager and generate the report without any issues.

Comment: To add to the above , when the affected users restart their PC a couple of times it starts working fine again.